# Phaser 3 Arcade physics not getting activated

Tags: phaser-framework

I am using Phaser 3(3.24) and following is my config to initialize the game

```
GAME_CONFIG: {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    scale: {
      width: 1200,
      height: 470,
      mode: Phaser.Scale.ScaleModes.NONE,
    },
    parent: 'marathon-game',
    physics: {
      default: 'arcade',
      fps: 60,
      arcade: {
        gravity: { y: 300 },
        debug: true,
      },
    },
  }
```

When I start my first scene and check this.scene.physics it returns undefined...any idea of why this would happen or what could I be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because your scene object is missing from the config. so if your scene is not a class use:

```
GAME_CONFIG: {
    ...the_rest_of_your_config
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
   }
```

Or:

```
GAME_CONFIG: {
    ...the_rest_of_your_config
    scene: name_of_your_scene_class_goes_here
   }
```